# Problem sourcing variables inside Upstart

Tags: 12.04, bash, upstart, source

I'm trying to use the variables defined in `/etc/environment` in an upstart script running on 12.04.

I'm able to export the variable to the child process but for some reason I not able to use them in the Upstart script stanza itself.

This works:

```
script
    . /etc/environment
    export NODE_ENV
    # node is able to read the NODE_ENV, wonderful!
    /usr/local/bin/node /path/to/app/app.js
end script
```

But if I try to introduce some conditional logic within the stanza then it will fail:

```
script

    . /etc/environment
    export NODE_ENV

    # ${NODE_ENV} is not set inside the stanza
    if [[ ${NODE_ENV} = 'production' ]]; then

        # this will never run
        /usr/local/bin/node /path/to/app/app.js
    fi

end script
```

Any ideas how I can access variables from sourced files inside the stanzas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
if [[ ${NODE_ENV} = 'production' ]]; then
```

is not valid in a POSIX-compliant shell, but does seem to be valid bash. I don't see the shell that upstart uses by default in `script` stanzas documented anywhere, but it's reasonable to assume that it uses `/bin/sh`, which is not bash on Debian/Ubuntu systems.

Try:

```
if [ "${NODE_ENV}" = 'production' ]; then
```

instead.

Comment: thanks, I tried this but it still doesn't work unfortunately. I took a look at the logs and this is what it's outputting: /proc/self/fd/9: 12: /proc/self/fd/9: [[staging: not found. This seems to indicate it's a problem with the conditional and not the variable to me. Very odd! the TERM env varible = LINUX not xterm if this makes any difference.

Comment: On second try this worked, thank you very much! It turns out that the double brackets were the real problem.